# Impersonate O365 user with API-only application

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, sharepoint, office365

A user logs into O365 and then visits SharePoint. I would like to put some client code in SharePoint that displays content from SharePoint and other data in O365.

However, instead of the browser calling SharePoint, Graph, Exchange etc., I want to have a C# based App Service in Azure with a RESTful API and then I will have my client code in SharePoint call the API which will then subsequently call SharePoint and other services in O365 on behalf of the client.

I am aware that it is possible to configure my App Service to authenticate with O365 and then when a client accesses it they will either be authenticated or redirected to login. The reason I am creating this question is because **I do not want to use this solution!**

I expect I cannot implement authentication through my API, because I need to support Multi Factor Authentication and I expect it is wise to allow Microsoft to handle this part.

So I am hoping for a good solution where I can let the user log in as normally and then when calling my App Service, they will include certain request headers etc. that will allow my App Service to impersonate the user when calling services in O365.

If the user is not properly authenticated for some reason, the API will just return an error and not attempt to handle any authentication issue itself.

It's important the App Service acts on behalf of the user and is not working under some service account with elevated privileges.

--

I can see the potential that my question will attract answers suggesting I should do something else than what I am describing. I hope for answers that will either tell me how to accomplish what I am looking for or, alternatively, tell me with some authority that it is not possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of

Comment: @juunas That seems like a good match for my challenge. Thanks! It involves manually registering an app with the Azure AD. OK, fine - but why does an app have to be registered when the client does not? The client can send some request header showing they are authorized, but if the app sends the same request header, it will be rejected unless it's registered? How does the service even know the difference between the app and a client?